# Is there a way to use saxon as the xquery processor in basex?

Tags: java, xquery, saxon, basex

I want to use schema awareness of saxon without dis-integrating basex which is already used in our code base. Is there a way to replace baseX Xquery processor with  saxon's schema aware Xquery processor ?
[This article](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/XSLT_Module) gives some instruction but they are for xslt processor.

Answer (score 3):

No, this wouldn't make any sense. BaseX provides an XML database so its XQuery processor knows how to take advantage of the stored representation of data in that database (including use of indexes) to optimize the query. Saxon has no knowledge of the internal data structures and indexes in the BaseX database so it wouldn't be able to access that data.

Comment: This is mostly, but not totally true.  Basex, both the gui and command line allow for read and query against raw xml files (other formats like csv and json are also candidates) outside of the context of a database.  Basex map support can reduce the need for a formal database with indexing support. In this context the question of what query processor might be used is completely valid (imho).

Comment: Yes. There are certainly situations where you can use Saxon to replace the BaseX query processor. But the headline question asks whether you can use Saxon "in BaseX" and the answer to that is no.